# How can I style "Tabs Example" from blueprintjs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, blueprintjs

I'm trying to use BlueprintJs in a small project and I'm coming up with a problem where the style does not appear as I would expect. As I'm sure it's something quite simple I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

I want to use the [Tabs](https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/components/tabs) component from their core library and just to get the feeling on how to use it I decided to use [the example they provide](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/blob/develop/packages/docs-app/src/examples/core-examples/tabsExample.tsx), and play around with it. To do so, I created a new project with `npx create-react-app MyApp --template typescript`, included the text within the GitHub link previously included into a new component, and imported and loaded that component from App.tsx:

```js
...

import { TabsExample } from "./tabs-example";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TabsExample id="tabs-example" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Where **TabsExample** is just the raw component example from BlueprintJs. At first I was expecting to run the app and obtain the *same look* as they have in their documentation, as I thought that BlueprintJs components already come with some default styling, but instead I get a plain text page, with no style nor tabs whatsoever: [image: Outcome of the raw code] As apparently styles do not come predefined I thought of including some classNames with values BlueprintJs understands to try and provide some styling, and my `<Tabs>` and `<Tab>` components now look like this:

```js
...
<Tabs
          animate={this.state.animate}
          className={`${Classes.TABS}`} // New added attribute
          id="TabsExample"
          key={this.state.vertical ? "vertical" : "horizontal"}
          renderActiveTabPanelOnly={this.state.activePanelOnly}
          vertical={this.state.vertical}
        >
          <Tab
            className={`${Classes.TAB_PANEL} react`} // New added attribute
            id="rx"
            title="React"
            panel={<ReactPanel />}
          />
...
```

But I still get that same plain text page. How can I style this example so that it looks the same way as it does in their documentation?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use their own css in your component that can be imported in the import area from your component:

import "@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint.css";

Answer (score 0):

If you use CSS you should be able to simply import the CSS files from the blueprint packages in your index.js file.

```
import "@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint.css";
import "@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css";
```

Or if you use SCSS

```
@import "@blueprintjs/core/src/blueprint.scss";
@import "@blueprintjs/icons/src/blueprint-icons.scss";
@import "@blueprintjs/core/lib/scss/variables.scss";
```